# How Java handles public methods in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a multithreading application, in my `ServerThread.run()` method, I use `ServerSocket.accept()` to receive new incoming connection. Everytime when a new connection arrives, `ServerThread` creates an other Thread named `ClientHandler` to handle the connection (Receiving/Sending data), and in my `ServerThread`, I have a `java.util.HashMap<ClientHandler, Socket>` to store the references of connected clients and the corresponding sockets.

In my `ServerThread`, I've implemented a few other public methods, such as `shutdown()` to stop the server thread, `disconnect(int id)` to shutdown the connection of a specific client etc. Those methods are usually called by my GUI, from the EDT thread.

I've tested the code, it works, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do this. I've read lots of Java multithreading tutorials, but they don't add other public methods in their custom `java.lang.Thread` subclass.

Especially in my `ServerThread.run()`, I have used the method `ServerSocket.accept()` which is supposed to be **blocking**. When I want to shutdown my `ServerThread`, I have to call `ServerSocket.close()` to force the thread to stop.

However, when I call for example `ServerThread.disconnect(int id)` to close the connection of a remote client, it works. Is the `ServerThread` supposed to be blocking on the `accept()` method ?

So, my code works, **but I don't know why**, and I'd like to know if one can add other public methods in a custom subclass of `java.lang.Thread` ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you don't add public methods to a Thread class is exactly because this sort of confusion arises - there's an intuition that the Thread class itself 'owns' the execution of those methods, whereas in Java it is -always- the calling thread that owns the execution.

When the EDT thread calls `ServerThread.disconnect(id)`, the code in the disconnect method is being run by the EDT thread, not the ServerThread.  The key point here is that the *Thread* ServerThread, and the *Object* ServerThread are not quite the same thing, semantically speaking - an Object can't be "blocked" in the same way that a Thread can, the expression doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @torquestomp, so in my case, I need to create a new class `Server` which holds the references of connected clients and the handler threads, it also contains other public methods with which I can close the connection of a specific client. The new `ServerThread` does nothing else but wait for new incoming connections and stores the reference of handler thread in the `Server` object. EDT manipulates handler threads using public methods of `Server` object which can be retrieved via a singleton `Server.getInstance()`. It's better in this way?

Comment: So it's not recommended to put public method in a thread, but it's not forbidden, since I still need the method `public void shutdown()` which turns the flag `running` to `false` and stops the `ServerThread`.

Comment: @vesontio It is not recommended to extend Thread at all. There is almost never a good reason to do it, and your case certainly doesn't need it.

Comment: Thank your for your reply, @MarkoTopolnik, but that's not my question here, anyway, thanks a lot.